# How do I detect what Serial port my arduino is connected to through processing?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

So I am creating a user interface for an arduino for a uni assignment. The assignment requires someone else to run my code on their own computer, so I need to find a way to automatically find the port that the arduino is connected to.

So far I have written this function, which is run in setup(), which loops through each port in Serial.list and sends a message to each port.

The arduino should then print a response to the serial port, which should then be read, confirming the connection.

```
void serial_port_setup() {
  delay(5000);
  String[] port_list = Serial.list();
  for (int i = 0; i < port_list.length; i++) {
    Serial test_port = new Serial(this, port_list[i], 115200);
    test_port.write('i');
    print("writing to port: ");
    println(port_list[i]);
    delay(500);
    if (test_port.available() > 0) {
      println("port available");
      String serial_string = test_port.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (serial_string.equals("initialising port")) {
        myPort = test_port;
        println("port found");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  println("couldnt find a port");
}
```

the arduino code I have is

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    if (Serial.read() == 'i') {
      Serial.println("initialising port");
      Serial.println("yay it worked");  
    } 
  }
}
```

When I run this code, these output lines are printed

```
writing to port: COM1
writing to port: COM3
couldnt find a port
```

So even though the arduino is attached to COM3, it either never responds to the message or the message is never written in the first place.
So why does this not work? Are there any better methods for finding the right serial port?

Comment: Can you clarify, is this running Arduino to Arduino, or Arduino to Windows PC? You talk about running one routine in `setup()` which I identify as being on the Arduino platform, but then you say the Arduino should respond which suggests Arduino on both ends. (I'm pretty new to this platform, so any confusion might be with me.)

Comment: Yeah thats my bad, so I'm running processing on my windows PC and I'm using it to control one arduino.

Comment: OK, so what code is running on the Windows PC? Last time I did anything like this (which is some time ago) it was fairly easy to run through the registry and get a list of installed COM ports (the list that appears in "Device Manager") and go from there.